# Mercurial from Subversion: moves, renames and tags

Tags: svn, mercurial, mercurial-convert

I have a subversion repo with the following layout:

```
svnrepo/projectA/trunk
svnrepo/projectA/tags
svnrepo/projectA/branches
svnrepo/projectB/trunk
svnrepo/projectB/tags
svnrepo/projectB/branches
```

which I would like to move to a mercurial repo with a revised layout:
hgrepo/projectA
hgrepo/projectB

What is the best way of doing this?  Some of my thoughts are:

**Option1**

Rearrange the paths in subversion (using svn move) to an intermediate format:

```
svnrepo/trunk/projectA
svnrepo/trunk/projectB
svnrepo/tags/projectA
svnrepo/tags/projectB
svnrepo/branches/projectA
svnrepo/branches/projectB
```

then hg convert on the svnrepo/trunk. Will this confuse hg importing?

**Option 2**
hg convert each of the projects/trunk into separate hg repos. Then merge them into a single hg repo (using hg init, hg pull -f projectA, etc).  I think this will lose the branch names and tags on the first imported project.

Comment: How are the different project related ? If they aren't related they shouldn't be in the same repo in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Mercurial, storing unrelated codebases in the same repository is a bad idea because it will

- Significantly complicate merging. Merges will depend on changes made to *all* projects, rather than just the project you're trying to merge.
- Cause storage and checkout overhead -- Mercurial, as far as I know, does not support checking out only subdirectories of a repository. You'd have to branch all projects at once.

The solution is to convert your single Subversion repository into multiple Mercurial repositories. Most conversion tools support this.

Answer (score 4):

Each project should be in its own Hg repository (to be able to get or tag only a specific project).

Remember than the directory you see in Subversion (trunk, tags, branches) will not exist in any modern (D)VCS, where branches and tags are first class citizen (i.e. meta-data directly managed by the tool), as opposed as simple directory resulting from a **cheap copy** (in SVN).

That means when you convert a SVN repository, you should not store directly any "trunk", "tags" or "branches" directory in the history of the Hg repo.

You should rather use a [tool like **`hgsubversion`**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) to import your SVN repo (like just "repo/projectA") into a Hg repo dedicated to the projectA. it will keep tags and branches of the orignal SVN project and convert them into Hg objects.
From [its documentation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hgsvn):

> All updates using `hgpullsvn` are made in the branch named from the last component of the SVN URL (e.g., if the SVN URL is `svn://server/myproj/branches/feature-ZZZ`, `hgpullsvn` will create and use the named branch '`feature-ZZZ`')

---

If you do not want "convert" but "syncing", [tonfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148532/tonfa) recommend [**`hgsubversion`**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion), although it "is currently in a state of flux due to heavy refactoring":

> Right now it is *not* ready for production use. You should only be using this if you're ready to hack on it, and go diving into the internals of Mercurial and/or Subversion.

Since `hgsvn` also allow some syncing through `hgpushsvn` and `hgpullsvn`... I would stick with `hgsvn` for now.

Comment: Please do not advocate hgsvn, hgsubversion is the preferred way to handle svn live syncing (as opposed to "final" conversions as done by hg convert).

Comment: you mixed the two tools now. (I still think hgsubversion is better, even if it doesn't advertize itself for production use, it is the long term solution).